# Как реализовать компонентный подход к организации кода на чистом JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте уважаемые посетители stackoverflow!
Имеется ряд вопросом, но о них чуть ниже. Заранее извиняюсь за большой текст, патался максимально подробно расписать, чтобы было понятно.
У меня есть страничка(учебная), на которой Список, Корзина и Карточки с продуктами.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытаюсь сделать все это дело с помощью компонентов. Создал классы, которые отвечают за определенную сущность на странице.
Класс для списка.

```
class ProductTypes {
    constructor(parentDOM, productsArray, activeType, ulClassName) {
        this.parentDOM = parentDOM;
        this.productsArray = productsArray;
        this.activeType = activeType;
        this.ulClassName = ulClassName;
    }

    // создание ul
    createList() {
        let ul = document.createElement("ul");
        ul.classList.add(this.ulClassName);
        this.parentDOM.appendChild(ul);
    }

    // создание li и добавление в ul
    createListItems() {
        let parent = document.querySelector("." + this.ulClassName);
        this.productsArray.map(item => {
            const { attribute, name } = item;
            let li = document.createElement("li");
            if (attribute === this.activeType) {
                li.setAttribute("data-name", attribute);
                li.setAttribute("data-default", this.activeType);
                li.textContent = name;
                li.classList.add("active-product");
                parent.appendChild(li);
            } else {
                li.textContent = name;
                li.setAttribute("data-name", attribute);
                parent.appendChild(li);
            }
        });
    }

    changeProductType() {
        let parent = document.querySelector("." + this.ulClassName);
        parent.addEventListener("click", async event => {
            if (event.target.tagName === "LI") {
                const type = event.target.getAttribute("data-name");
                this.switchActiveClass(event.target, "active-product", parent);

                app.getProductsItem(type); // функция из APP ?
            }
        });
    }

    switchActiveClass(element, className, parent) {
        parent.childNodes.forEach(el => {
            el.classList.remove(className);
            el.removeAttribute("class");
            if (el.getAttribute("data-default")) {
                el.removeAttribute("data-default");
            }
        });
        element.classList.add(className);
    }

    render() {
        this.createList(); // ?
        this.createListItems(); // ?
        this.changeProductType(); // ?
    }
}

const productTypesList = new ProductTypes(
    ROOT_PRODUCT_TYPES,
    productsType,
    "sandwiches",
    "menu-list"
);

productTypesList.render();
```

Класс для карточек с товарами:

```
class ProductItem {
    constructor(name, description, category, image, price, type) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.category = category;
        this.image = image;
        this.price = price;
        this.type = type;
    }

    render() {
        const html = `
      <div class="item-wrapper" data-name="${this.name}">
          <div class="item-wrapper__img"><img src="data${this.image}" alt="${this.category}"></div>
          <div class="item-wrapper__name">${this.name}</div>
          <div class="item-wrapper__description" data-atr="${this.type}">${this.description}</div>
          <div class="item-wrapper__price">Цена: ${this.price} руб.</div>
          <div class="item-wrapper__count">
              <span>Количество</span>
            <div class="item-count__button">
              <button class="btn-count" data-atr="decrease">
                <i class='fas fa-minus' data-atr='decrease'></i>
              </button>
              <span class="item-count__field">1</span>
              <button class="btn-count" data-atr="increase">
                <i class='fas fa-plus' data-atr='increase'></i>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="item-wrapper__inbasket">
              <button class="btn-style basket-btn-add" data-name="${this.name}" data-atr="inBasket">
                В корзину
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>`;
        return html;
    }
}
```

Для api запроса я создал так же отдельный класс:

```
class FetchApi {
    constructor(url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    async fetchData(typeProduct) {
        try {
            let response = await fetch(this.url);
            if (response.ok) {
                let data = await response.json();
                const products = data.menu.filter(product => {
                    if (typeProduct === product.category) return product;
                });
                return products;
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
}
const request = new FetchApi(URL);
```

Далее чтобы компоненты 'ничего не знали друг о друге наприямую', я создал отдельный класс APP в котором у меня будет происходить вызов функция для рендера данных в корзине и данных с карточками товара(в зависимости выбранного типа из списка).

```
class App {
    constructor() {}

    // вызвать рендер продуктов
    // вызвать рендер корзины, когда будет в нее что-то добавлено

    async getProductsItem(productType) {
        ROOT_RIGHT_SIDE.innerHTML = "";

        const products = await request.fetchData(productType); // массив с продуктами
        // console.log(products);
        products.map(product => {
            const { name, description, category, image, price, type } = product;
            ROOT_RIGHT_SIDE.innerHTML += new ProductItem(
                name,
                description,
                category,
                image,
                price,
                type
            ).render();
        });
    }
}
const app = new App();
```

Вопросы такие:

1. Я не знаю как правильно организовать вызов методов из APP, чтобы происходил ререндер карточек. Как это я сделал сейчас, в классе ProductTypes у меня есть метод changeProductType(), в котором вызывается метод класса app.getProductsItem(type). Там у меня идет вызов метода из класса FetchApi, который возврвщает массив с продуктами определенных типов.
2. В классе App в методе getProductsItem(), по полученному массиву я прохожусь и добавляю на страницу экземплары класса ProductItem (получается - одна итерация - один экземплар). - Я так же не знаю, правильно ли так делать )
3. Не знаю где и как объявить методы обработчика клика для кнопок +, -, в корзину. Добавлял, как отдельный метод соответственно в классе через addeventlistener, но так как я создаю контент через шаблон, ошибка что карточки с нужным враппером еще нет.
4. Не нравится(но я и не знаю, как правильно), как я вызвал функции создания ul и li в классе ProductTypes, вызвал я их в методе рендер.

Благодарю за внимание и еще раз извиняюсь за такой большой текст :)